# Codeigniter shows 404 no page found.

Tags: php, codeigniter, lamp

Well I have a strange problem in my Codeigniter page. I have a controller class `books.php`

```
> <?php
> //echo 'Hello';
> class Books extends CI_Controller{
>     function __construct() {
>         parent::__construct();
>     }
>     
>     
>     function main()
>     {
>         $this->load->view('main_view');
>     }
>     
>     function input()
>     {
>         $this->load->view('input_view');
>     } } ?>
```

Now if I point my browser to `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/books` it shows `404 Page not found.` Now If I add a `echo 'Hello';` just above the class declaration, it shows hello and at the top of the page and after that line the same 404 error.Is this due to permission roblem. `books.php` have `777` permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> <?php
> //echo 'Hello';
> class Books extends CI_Controller{
>     function __construct() {
>         parent::__construct();
>     }
>     
>     
>     function index()
>     {
>         $this->load->view('main_view');
>     }
>     
>     function input()
>     {
>         $this->load->view('input_view');
>     } } ?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks its working. So what if I want to go to the input. Means what will be its URL because `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/books/input` again shows 404 error

Comment: Ok its howing..I missed `/books` at URL. Thnks anyway

Answer (score 2):

When accessing:

> http://www.example.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/books

the default router will actually load up

> http://www.example.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/books/index

It is therefore looking for the **index** method.

Try adding the method or calling either of the method that you have defined:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/books/main
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/books/input
```

Also, you should refrain from having 777 permissions on your files.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. Now suppose I have a menu for my website. I replaced my main() with index(). So `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/books/` shows the main_view. Now at menu what should be the anchor to the index(), because I tried putting <a href="/books">Main</a> , but it adds `/books` every time I clicked the link.

Comment: <?php echo anchor('books', 'Books');>

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `index()` function. Refer to [CodeIgniter URLs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) topic in their user guide to find out more about their segment-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a index function inside your books.php or just for a sake of test just rename main function signature as follows -

function index()

> ```
> {
>     $this->load->view('main_view');
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code

```
<?php
> //echo 'Hello';
> class Books extends CI_Controller{
>     public function index() {
>         echo "check";
>     }
>     
>     
>     function main()
>     {
>         $this->load->view('main_view');
>     }
>     
>     function input()
>     {
>         $this->load->view('input_view');
>     } } ?>
```